# Animate stuff like in jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, wpf, jquery-animate

I was wondering if there is a function like animate in jQuery, but for C# 4.0 ?

When people clicks a button, some panel and other controls must disappear, then I thought of using some simple animation to make it prettier with opacity, and there is another task that is to move some panels in a right order, then I thought again in using some easing moviments like in jQuery animate() function.

Comment: question: Why the editor removed the "WPF" part?  I guess it is important to say that I am not using windows forms but the windows foundation platform for the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most direct equivalent to jQuery's `anmiate()` is the WPF's [DoubleAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx).  For animating more than one property the equivalent is [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx).  There are also more sophisticated reusable animation capabilities included in the free Expression Blend SDK such as [FluidMoveBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.layout.fluidmovebehavior%28Expression.40%29.aspx) and `UseFluidLayout` with the [ExtendedVisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726461%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx).

Here is an introduction to the Blend animations:

- [DYNAMIC LAYOUT AND TRANSITIONS IN EXPRESSION BLEND 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2010/03/16/dynamic-layout-and-transitions-in-expression-blend-4.aspx)